# What does "most recent call last" mean in python error message?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I'm not a English speaker,i can understand what "most recent call" means，and i know what "last" means,but when they combined like this,i was totally confused.

Comment: That message is followed by a stack trace. To ensure you read this in the right order, it clarifies that the calls are shown in order, the first call coming first, and the last call comes at the end, *last*.

Comment: So this sentence acctually means "most recent call is in the last", is that correct?

Comment: Yes, "most recent call is at the end".

Comment: Thank you for helping me, this problem really bothered me.